# verify a paypal email only

Tags: php, paypal

I know there is the addressverify operation on the paypal API, but the docs say that it's also a requirement to send the address and post code of the user along with the email.

I don't want to have to collect the address of the user, I only want to make sure if I make a payment to that email address it'll not fail. And I need to be able to do this independent of any transaction. I need to know today that the email I'm going to send a transaction to in three weeks is a valid paypal account.

is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [GetVerifiedStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/) function of the PayPal API. That should do what you need.

Comment: this only checks if the user is a "verified" PayPal user. Not a PayPal user in general.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt was the adaptive payments api GetUserLimits, but it didn't work for me. My understanding it it is a restricted API.

I ended up hacking together a solution based on the fact that the [adaptive payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/) api throws an error when a valid email is used as the sender and recipient of a transaction. I look for this case to test if an email is valid. (here is the ruby code)

```
 def getApi()
  PayPal::SDK.configure(
  :mode      => "sandbox",  # Set "live" for production
  :app_id    => "yourAppId",
  :username  => "yourUsername",
  :password  => "yourPassword",
  :signature => "yourSignature" )

  api = PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments.new
 end

 def pay(senderEmail, receiverEmail, amount, trackingId)
  @api = getApi

  # Build request object
  @pay = @api.build_pay({
    :actionType => "PAY",
    :cancelUrl =>  "https://yourwebsite.com/cancel/" + trackingId,
    :currencyCode => "USD",
    :feesPayer => "SENDER",
    :ipnNotificationUrl => "https://yourwebsite.com/ipn_notify/" + trackingId,
    :receiverList => {
      :receiver => [{
        :amount => amount,      :email => receiverEmail }] },
    :returnUrl =>  http://www.yourwebsite.com/completed/" + trackingId})

  @pay.sender.email = senderEmail
  #@pay.sender.accountId = 23434
  # Make API call & get response
  puts @pay.inspect
  @response = @api.pay(@pay)

  if @response.success?
    @response.payKey
    completeUrl = @api.payment_url(@response)
    return {url: completeUrl, payKey: @response.payKey}
  else
    raise AccountException.new(@response.error[0])
  end
 end

 def isValidAccount(email)
  begin
    result = pay(email, email, 1.0)
  rescue AccountException
    puts 'in rescue'
    senderAndReceiverCantbeTheSameErrorCode = 579033
    if $!.innerError.errorId == senderAndReceiverCantbeTheSameErrorCode
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
 end
```

Comment: can you have in php?